# Using Apex Codes to Save an image of the Salesforce Dashboard at certain time

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, image-formula

I need help with creating apex codes for a scheduler to save an image of my company's dashboard once everyday into the Salesforce document folder.

From This post [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hIoeAAE) I understand you can get an image of the Salesforce Dashboard but I still do not know how to use the apex class to save that image into the Salesforce Document Folder and also how to schedule that time that the apex program is suppose to save the image.

Can anyone help me create an apex class code that can:

- schedule a certain time to take an image of the Salesforce Dashboard
  and save the image into the Salesforce document folder?

Comment: Do you need to save a specific image that is part of your dashboard? Or do you want to save the entire dashboard as you see it in your browser as an image?

Comment: i want to save the entire dashboard as an image

Comment: I have no clue if this would work but you may be able to add your dashboard to a visualforce page, and then use apex to regularly turn the page into a pdf. You could than save the pdf in the document folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have the URL, its easy to convert it into base64.

```
    String base64Data = '';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(ImageURL);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
    base64Data =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);
```

Once you have the base64 data, you will just have to insert into an `Document` record you want to create.

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Name = 'SF Dashboard Image.jpeg';
doc.body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
doc.folderId = '00l900000027wOx'; //your folder id

insert doc;
```

Now to the scheduling part, you can write the above logic in a [batch class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) and [schedule the batch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) class to run everyday.